# A phrase for critically important

Tags: phrase-requests

Can you please help me to find an idiom/phrase that would describe something as being of high importance.

e.g. These files are ... (critically important).

Comment: "crucial", perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

- Essential
- Vital
- Crucial
- (Business- or Mission-) critical

Or maybe:

- Necessary
- Required

Many of these could be qualified (e.g. "...*necessary* for proper processing of the case")

You may want something more specific to a particular case - feel free to elaborate further.